# Finding a limit of a recurrence relation

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

I want to find the limit of a recursive sequence given below:
$$p_{n+1}=\frac{p_n^2+k}{2p_n}, \ \ \forall k \in \mathbb{R}$$
How would I go about it? I know this converges because it is the NR approximation for square roots. Thus, I ask too, if whether the limit of that relation above will give me the square root of $k$.

If you could write it in the most elementary of terms and with as much intuition as possible, that would be appreciated.

Comment: In case you have already proved convergence, we know the limit exists and is unique (say $L$). Then, from the recurrence, we have $L=\dfrac{L^2+k}{2L}$ from which we conclude $L=\sqrt{k}$ (the negative solution is discarded since the successive convergents will be non-negative for a given seed).

Comment: If $k\ge 0$, then $p_{n+1}-\sqrt{k}=\dfrac{(p_n-\sqrt{k})^2}{2p_n}$. In general, you might want to show your sequence is eventually monotone and bounded, and therefore convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’ve proven the limit $L$ exists you can let $n\to \infty$ so the recurrence becomes 
$$L=\frac{L^2+k}{2L}$$
So $L^2=k$. Provided $p_n>0$ and $k>0$ you can conclude $L=\sqrt{k}$

Comment: The principal part of this problem is showing whether or not the limit exists. Once we know whether it exists or not, the calculation is straightforward.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein The OP seemed interested in calculating it as they said “I know this converges”

Comment: True, the OP did say that. However, the NR approximation does not always converge, so one needs to check that it does for the square root function. Proof of convergence is also relevant since the OP only says that $k\in\mathbb{R}$ without assuming that $k\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We can show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=\sqrt{k}$.
First, by the AM-GM inequality, we can see that
$$p_{n+1}=\frac{p_n^2+k}{2p_n} \ge \sqrt{k}$$
Thus,  $p_{n}-\sqrt{k} \ge 0$ for all $n$. Now,

$$\frac{p_{n+1}-\sqrt{k}}{p_{n}-\sqrt{k}}=\frac{\frac{p_n}{2}+\frac{k}{2p_n}-\sqrt{k}}{p_{n}-\sqrt{k}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left( \sqrt{p_n} - \frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{p_n}}\right)^2}{p_{n}-\sqrt{k}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{p_n-\sqrt{k}}{p_n}$$
$$<\frac{1}{2}$$
Thus, $p_n-\sqrt{k}<\frac{1}{2^n}(p_0-\sqrt{k})$ which is enough to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (p_n-\sqrt{k})=0$

Comment: What if $k<0$? The OP only says that $k\in\mathbb{R}$, not that $k\ge 0$.